# docker not running despite running on foreground and -it options

Tags: docker

I have an application that utilizes Apache2/Tomcat on Ubuntu container. It has scripts in "/etc/init.d/apatomcat"

This is my Dockerfile:

This is what I do on cmd I tried (including -D option with foreground, etc).

docker start & attach

docker run & exect

```
root@docker:~/tomcat-Docker/ubuntu# cat Dockerfile 
FROM ubuntu:14.04
ENV http_proxy 'http://wsa.corp.com:8000'
ENV https_proxy 'http://wsa.corp.com:8000'
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive 
ENV apatomcat_DIR=/var/apatomcat/apatomcat/
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

COPY apt.conf /etc/apt/apt.conf
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y vim python2.7 openjdk-7-jdk ssh ant 

CMD chmod a+rwx /etc/profile.d/apatomcat.sh

COPY apatomcat.conf /etc/apatomcat/apatomcat.conf

CMD /etc/init.d/apatomcat start &
CMD /etc/init.d/ssh restart &

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT service ssh restart && bash
root@docker9:~/tomcat-Docker/ubuntu# docker build -t apatomcat .

docker start 9e1752bf7650  
docker attach 9e1752bf7650

root@docker:~/tomcat-Docker/ubuntu# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES



root@docker:~/tomcat-Docker/ubuntu# docker run -i -t apatomcat  /bin/bash
root@docker:~/tomcat-Docker/ubuntu# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

Despite reading up on countless articles, still don't seem to stay on and shutting down. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for `docker logs <container>` to help tell you why?   Also, I think you're only allowed one `CMD` line (I'm new to Docker), and containers only last as long as the process they run in CMD.  In your case, it exits after the `CMD chmod` part.

Comment: you are right, figured it out days upon post. thanks for getting back!!